# Install Visual Studio Project After Downloading From Azure

Tags: visual-studio, repository

my team stores applications in azure repository. I downloaded my coworker's application in zip file. After I load the project in Visual Studio 2019, there are a lot of missing references and I cannot compile the code. My coworker uploaded application using TFS. Do I need to install anything to run the code? In ReactJs, I run npm install. How about Visual Studio apps? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [Nuget Package Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages-manually-using-visual-studio)?

Comment: Most likely, you need to download the whole solution; not just one application project folder. If your team is working on Azure DevOps, you should do so too - even if you do not intend to make changes and contribute to the repository.

Comment: I run Nuget Package Restore and there are two references are still missing, Json and NewtonSoft. They both are installed in the project already. But there are yellow triangle signs in the reference folder.

Answer (score 0):

OKay, I followed Joachim's post, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages-manually-using-visual-studio and then uninstall, reinstall the Json.Net, NewtonSoft package. Now the application can be compiled. Thanks everyone.